# Jquery ajax call not working in django application for dependent drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I am trying to fetch localities based on the city in my django application using jquery ajax call but this does not seem to be working. What is actually going wrong here? Help

***html***

```
<h1>Dependent Dropdown</h1>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#selectcities").change(function () { 
        const city_id = $(this).val();  

        $.ajax({                       
            url: '/getdetails',   
            data: {
                'city_id': city_id       
            },
            success: function (data) { 
                console.log(data)
                $("#selectlocalities").html(data); 
               
            }
        });

    });
</script>
<form action="/submit/" method="POST">
    <h4>Select city</h4>
    <select id="selectcities" name="selectcity">
        <option selected>Select City</option>
        {% for city in cities %}
        <option val="{{ city.id }}">{{city.name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <h4>Select Locality</h4>
        <select id="selectlocalities" name="selectlocality">
            <option selected>Select Locality</option>
        </select>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">
</form>
```

***views.py***

```
def pageload(request):
    cities=city.objects.all()
    context={'cities': cities}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)

def load_localities(request):
    city_id = request.GET.get('city_id')
    localities = locality.objects.filter(city_id=city_id).all()
    context={'localities':localities}
    return render(request, 'locality_dropdown_list_options.html',context)
```

Comment: what does `console.log(data)` prints ?

Comment: It prints nothing, I added it to check if data is actually reaching there or not

Comment: Is ajax call executed ? Open your network tab -> XHR you find more info about ajax call there